# Can't see contents of Redis script cache

Tags: caching, redis

How can I find a Redis script by its SHA? I know that I can run a script by its SHA using `EVALSHA`, or find if it's cached with `SCRIPT EXISTS`, but I found the SHA in the slow log, and I don't want to run it, just see which script it is so I can figure out why it's slow. How an I access the Redis script cache where it keeps scripts with their SHAs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of functionality doesn't exist in Redis, up to and including v4.

Instead, what you could do, is collect all your scripts and calculate their SHA1 sums (doesn't have to be in Redis). Then, pinpointing the culprit should be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your help. @Itamar I used two different sites, hash generated for the same script was different. Is that possible?